# I can't call the Intent class inside the thread

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to show message after redirect the current class to another class.but this code 
just display the message, not redirect to another class.I also tried separate Handler class,But not working.  pls help to solve the prbm.

```
 but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
        public void onClick(final View v) 
          {

             new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                       /*  sample code */
                         showToast();

                        }
                     catch (IOException e) 
                        {

                        }           

                    }

            }


                     ).start();



    }

        public void showToast() {
            hd.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), List.class);
                      startActivity(myIntent); 
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Redirect to main menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
               });

        }
        });
```

Comment: have u tried `Intent myIntent = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, List.class);` instead of `v.getContext()`

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K Ya... Tnx it works...

Comment: Even if this works (for the moment), it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rule :** Do not try UI stuff in threads.

**Work Around :**  You can use AsyncTask in Android to carry on the heavy stuff in background while showing progress dialog in foreground. On end of the background thread's execution, do your UI work.

Read this to know more about the usage of AsynTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: then how can i call the intent?.

Comment: @Shail it is not the answer. It is the tip. try to make it complete. Give him some link or some description about your **Rule**

Comment: but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
        public void onClick(final View v) 
          {
          
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), List.class);
                      startActivity(myIntent); 
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Redirect to main menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       
          }

      }

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to show a message after the Activity has started, set a flag up from the first Activity, and use the next Activity you're starting to launch the toast in question (assuming the flag is there).

You could also abandon the toast idea, and just send that message through the NotificationManager, and then automatically delete it quickly if you want it to stay there only temporarily. Using the NotificationManager is the ideal solution if the Activity you're calling is not your own.

In any case, if you still need to use a thread, then use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Just don't make the same mistake of showing the toast from the background thread. That still could create some trouble for you down the line (even if you manage to somehow get the context in there).

Answer (score 0):

use your class context in intent like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes in your `showToast()` method:

Use:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(name_of_your_current_activity.this,
 List.class); startActivity(myIntent);
```

Instead:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), List.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

and instead of using Thread use [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform your action, within onPostExcute().

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this use handler to call other class

```
       Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    handle.sendMessage(msg);


Handler handle = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        super.handleMessage(msg);

        if(msg.what == 0){
                  //call intent
            };
                };
```

Comment: use context of your application